# Average/General RAID 0 "Chunk Size"?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, raid, disk-utility

**EDIT:** this got closed as being "opinion based". i disagree! the facts are, i have to choose one of five Chunk Size options when creating a RAID on Mac. i don't know which size to choose for a general purpose drive. i could use advice from those more knowledgeable on such matters on which size to choose. Not opinions, but factually & technically which size would be optimal for such purposes.

---

*fyi: using macOS 13 Ventura on a Macbook Pro M1 Max.*

i have an older Western Digital My Passport Pro with a Thunderbolt 2 interface (using an Apple Thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter/dongle). it's the one with 2 HHD's in it.

it came setup as RAID 0 but formatted in "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)".
i want to reformat it to use "APFS" instead.

so using Disk Utility, i deleted the RAID and reformatted the drives. then upon using Disk Utility's RAID Assistant, i selected the RAID type to RAID 0 and selected the two newly reformatted drives. then on the next screen (Set Properties), under where you choose the Name & Format, there's a setting to select a "Chunk Size".

i've never seen this option before (granted it's been many many many years since i needed to re-RAID something), and i can't figure out which option to select...

the Chunk size options are: 16K, 32K, 64K, 128K, or 256K.

everything i've found to read on the subject says that's determined by how big the files you're working with are. to choose a small K when working with large videos & graphics files; and to choose a large K when working with smaller text based files.

**but what if you have a mix for ALL kinds of files & sizes?**

**what would be the optimal Chunk size for a general purpose drive?**

**yes, i could just choose the middle one (64K) but i don't know if that's optimally average or if leaning to the left or right of middle would be better for such a mix of file types & sizes.**

i did contact WD support and instead of just telling me what Chunk Size the drives came from the factory set at, their 'only' solution is for me to download/install their disk utility app. i had problems with that app working well two computers ago, so chose to not install it on my previous & current systems. i would rather a solution to be knowledge rather than 'another' app to clutter my mac innards just for this purpose.
thanks.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Mac users are simply not used to having to specify sector/chunk sizes etc on anything; they're simply never given the choice, the system chooses. The user accepts without even necessarily knowing what the value ever is. You *can* do it from Terminal… but most don't. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118302 and https://www.zdnet.com/article/chunks-the-hidden-key-to-raid-performance/ [neither really gives an answer, btw]

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin for the reopen vote & for the info. yeah, i can't find a way to just let the system decide & i can't bypass choosing one of those options. so just trying to get a sense of which one to choose for optimal general purpose use.

Comment: You'd have to research or rely on research others did, for example https://www.overclock.net/threads/ssd-raid-0-stripe-size-differences-benchmarks-raid-0-mixing-different-drives-vs-same-drive-benchmarks.1535527/

Comment: Thanks @JoepvanSteen. i gather from that article that i should actually choose 16K. hmmm.

Comment: i have another of these drives that i've not reformatted yet. is there a way to find out what chunk size it is using? the Mac Disk Utility as well as a Terminal "diskutil info" doesn't say.

Comment: Are you using hdd or ssd?  Is your workload biased heavily to reads, writes or a balance?  What is your reason for wanting RAID0?

Comment: @davidgo, it's an HHD. it came RAID 0. i don't really have any reason to not keep it as such. i just wanted the APFS format for it. as far as workload, i'd say a general balance of small to large file sizes & a variety of file types. i probably won't work directly off of the drive, so mostly for storage & access (generally).

Comment: @DavidPostill, please re-open this that you closed. it's not "opinion-based" as you say.

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE for your comments, and THANKS to those who re-opened this. when this got closed, i asked the same thing & got a satisfactory answer there @ https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460163/how-to-discover-choose-raid-chunk-size , so i guess you can close this again since the answer is at the other posting. much appreciation.